# Pandas: populate off diagonals of matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

Suppose I have an NxN matrix (df).  I would like to populate all but the diagonals of df with 0s.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.eye(n)`:

`pd.DataFrame(np.eye(5) * np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))`

Answer (score 2):

np.diag should be sufficient:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(7, size=[6, 6]))
np.diag(np.diag(df))

array([[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]])
```

Comment: This is pretty clever.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=[5, 5]), list('ABCDE'), list('VWXYZ'))
print(df)

   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  4  6  7  5  4
B  9  7  3  3  0
C  1  9  7  8  2
D  1  9  7  9  9
E  6  6  6  6  1
```

***`np.eye`***

```
df.mul(np.eye(len(df), dtype=int))

   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  4  0  0  0  0
B  0  7  0  0  0
C  0  0  7  0  0
D  0  0  0  9  0
E  0  0  0  0  1
```

***reconstruct***
*filling in the diagonals*

```
z = np.zeros_like(df)
r = np.arange(len(df))
z[r, r] = df.values[r, r]

pd.DataFrame(z, df.index, df.columns)

   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  4  0  0  0  0
B  0  7  0  0  0
C  0  0  7  0  0
D  0  0  0  9  0
E  0  0  0  0  1
```

***`np.triu_indices`***
*fill in off diagonals*

```
i, j = np.triu_indices(len(df), 1)

df.values[i, j] = 0
df.values[j, i] = 0

df

   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  4  0  0  0  0
B  0  7  0  0  0
C  0  0  7  0  0
D  0  0  0  9  0
E  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `fill_diagonal` to fill new zeros matrix with diagonal from old matrix.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
A_d = np.zeros_like(A)
np.fill_diagonal(A_d, A.diagonal())

# A_d
# array([[1, 0],
#        [0, 4]])
```